# How to position third button on the same line at the far right

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

I have 2 buttons that are at the far left, beside each other.  I need the third button to be positioned at the far right, but **not using margin-left**.  I need a different way to do that using slds.  I've tried many different things like slds-m-right_x-small and alignment bump right and left but nothing has moved the button over like margin-left does.

This is the html:

```
<template>
    <div class="c-container">
        <lightning-layout class=slds-is-relative multiple-rows="true" >
            <lightning-layout-item flexibility="grow"
                                   padding="around-medium"
                                   size="12"
                                   class="slds-is-relative slds-m-bottom_small_small ">
                <div class="page-section page-header">
                    <lightning-card >
                        <h3 slot="title">
                            <div>
                                <span>
                                    <lightning-button style="font-weight:normal;font-size:13px"
                                                      label="Sales Performance Report"
                                                      title="Sales Performance Report"
                                                      onclick={handleSalesPerformanceReportClick}
                                                      class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
                                    <lightning-button style="font-weight:normal;font-size:13px"
                                                      label="Preorder Report"
                                                      title="Preorder Report"
                                                      onclick={handlePreOrderReportClick}
                                                      class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
                                </span>
                                <span if:true={isLTRLive}>
                                         <lightning-button label="Pulse"
                                                           title="Pulse"
                                                           onclick={handlePulseClick}
                                                           class="slds-m-left_x-small"
                                                           style="margin-left:+350px; font-weight:normal; font-size:13px" ></lightning-button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div if:false={editable} slot="footer">
                                Sales Performance
                            </div>
                        </h3>
                        <div>
                            <div if:true={error}>
                                <p>{errorString}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div if:false={error}><lightning-datatable
                                    class="last-row-bold"
                                    data={salesPerformanceData}
                                    columns={columns}
                                    hide-checkbox-column
                                    key-field="id">
                            </lightning-datatable>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div if:false={error}><p>NOTE: xxxyyyzzz</p></div>
                    </lightning-card>
                </div>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </div>
</template>
```

Right now the buttons look like this:
[image]

Comment: Have you thought about using [slds-grid](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/)?

Comment: No, I've never used that before.

Comment: It is probably the answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [layout-item](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout-item/example) component to have this without using margin.
[image]

A sample code from above link

```
     <lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item>
             <lightning-button label="Sales Performance Report" class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-button label="Sales Performance Report" class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item alignment-bump="left">
            <lightning-button label="Sales Performance Report" class="slds-m-right_x-small"></lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-button label="Sales Performance Report" class="slds-m-right_x-small"></lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
```

**alignment-bump**  - Specifies a direction to bump the alignment of adjacent layout items. Allowed values are left, top, right, bottom.

Comment: Thanks.  I changed my code to look like this, but now the last button is pushed right up against the second button, instead of being at the far right.

Answer (score -3):

This is how it is now.  The Pulse button is right beside the second button, instead of being at the far right.

```
<template>
    <div class="c-container">
        <lightning-layout class=slds-is-relative multiple-rows="true" >
            <lightning-layout-item flexibility="grow"
                                   padding="around-medium"
                                   size="12"
                                   class="slds-is-relative slds-m-bottom_small_small ">
                <div class="page-section page-header">
                    <lightning-card >
                        <h3 slot="title">
                            <div>

                                <lightning-layout-item>
                                    <lightning-button style="font-weight:normal;font-size:13px"
                                                      label="SAP Sales Performance Report"
                                                      title="SAP Sales Performance Report"
                                                      onclick={handleSalesPerformanceReportClick}
                                                      class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
                                </lightning-layout-item>

                                <lightning-layout-item>
                                    <lightning-button style="font-weight:normal;font-size:13px"
                                                      label="SAP Preorder Report"
                                                      title="SAP Preorder Report"
                                                      onclick={handlePreOrderReportClick}
                                                      class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
                                </lightning-layout-item>

                                <lightning-layout-item alignment-bump="left">
                                <span if:true={isLTRLive}>
                                         <lightning-button label="Pulse"
                                                           title="Pulse"
                                                           class="slds-m-right_x-small"
                                                           onclick={handlePulseClick}
                                                           style="font-weight:normal; font-size:13px" ></lightning-button>
                                </span>
                                </lightning-layout-item>

                            </div>
                            <div if:false={editable} slot="footer">
                                Sales Performance
                            </div>
                        </h3>
                        <div>
                            <div if:true={error}>
                                <p>{errorString}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div if:false={error}><lightning-datatable
                                    class="last-row-bold"
                                    data={salesPerformanceData}
                                    columns={columns}
                                    hide-checkbox-column
                                    key-field="id">
                            </lightning-datatable>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div if:false={error}><p>NOTE: RSG retailers will reflect Fiscal Period and Fiscal Year time period whereby all other retailers will reflect Calendar Month and Calendar Year time period</p></div>
                    </lightning-card>
                </div>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer to the question. StackExchange is not an online forum. Please rather make your question more precise and use the comments functionality to indicate problems with answers.

Comment: I did try to add a comment but I wanted to include the code changes I made but I could not include all the code in the comment because of the character limits.  That's why I created an answer instead.

Comment: You can edit the question and add the updated code their. Also, you should not use flexibility="grow" in lightning-layout for this scenario.

Comment: I did remove the flexibility='grow'.  It didn't affect the button positions but it's good to remove it if it's not needed.  Thank you.